# When I Restore in Elasticsearch 2.2 and Index more docs at the same time, how ES Behaves?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, backup

I am restoring an Index in ES, and indexing more docs of the same type in the same Index, how ES behaves?

Is there any performance impact?

If I am restoring documents with the same ID that are being referenced? What happens?

Any happens before relationship I should care about?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? When an index is been restored, it's closed, which means you cannot index any documents into it.

Comment: That's the answer I wanted

Comment: Then it's the answer that you are going to get. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an index is been restored, it's closed, which means you cannot index any documents into it.